# Django 1.4 datefield and sqlite problems

Tags: django, sqlite, django-admin

I have a model like this:

```
class Some_Model(django.Model):
    name         = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    some_date    = models.DateField(default=datetime.now)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
```

.. which I manage via django admin. There, I can select a date from the js widget. The date is stored as `yyyy-mm-dd` in the sqlite table, where the field is a `datetime` field. When selecting the value again, via `Some_Model.objects.all()[0]`, the field returns `None`, since the time information is missing, I guess. What is this? It used to work in django 1.3, but after migration, it fails now.

Answer (score 3):

Timezone changes were a big part of 1.4. I'm not positive your issue is related to this, but I suspect it is. A few suggestions:

1. Read the [django docs on the timezone changes in 1.4](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/timezones/).
2. Try setting `USE_TZ = False` in your settings file. This should force django datetimes to behave like 1.3 and may fix your problem.
3. Replace `default=datetime.now` with `default=now` where `now` is imported from `django.utils.timezone`. The django supplied `now` will automatically include or exclude timezone data depending on the value of `USE_TZ` in the settings.